# SSRS - select where parameter and fixed value

Tags: sql-server, select, ssrs, parameter, like

So there is a lot of stuff about using SSRS parameters to select multiple values but nothing about using both a parameter and a fixed value using the in select statement.

So what I'm trying to do is this:

```
select * from table where id in (Parameter_1, 'total')
```

Yet when I do that it complains its can't find 'Parameter_1'.

I've gotten another report to work when its just:

```
select * from table where id = Parameter_2
```

but this this isn't good enough in this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was actually with the parameter itself.

I had to create a new one in the query called @Parameter_1 and then set it up in the query parameter tab and delete the old one.

Really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly create a stored procedure to do this task and pass values from ssrs to avoid multiple execution plans.